# E: Unable to locate package libprotobuf-c0-dev

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

I am trying to install *libprotobuf-c0-dev* package on Ubuntu 20.04 with `sudo apt-get install -y libprotobuf-c0-dev`, but it's giving the following error when trying to install it:

```
E: Unable to locate package libprotobuf-c0-dev
```

Comment: Please take a look at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libprotobuf&searchon=names&suite=focal&section=all

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu   (do you have 'universe' enabled?  and why would you use '-y' if you're not 100% sure of the results before hand?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu. In general you may want to use `apt search` or `apt-cache search` from the command line to find packages for which you know constituting name parts. Clearly here you knew `protobuf` or `libprotobuf`. Pipe to `grep` to filter the resulting list down to your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protocol Buffers C static library and headers (*libprotobuf-c0-dev*) has been updated to *libprotobuf-c-dev* in Ubuntu 16.04 and later. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install libprotobuf-c-dev
```

Comment: Thanks, @karel.  Its working.